# Passing the return from a yield block to a variable in the calling method

Tags: ruby, block, yield

So, I'm not seeing exactly what I'm looking for in the search.
Here's my question. I'm learning Ruby and RoR right now - and I've got a question I can't seem to find the answer to.
So, here's my play code:

```
class BlocksAndIterators
  def yield_madness(a, b)
    my_funky_pi = ((a*b) - (b+a)) / 3.14
    my_yield = yield(my_funky_pi, a)
    "my_funky_pi: #{my_funky_pi}\nmy_yield: #{my_yield}"
  end
end

bi = BlocksAndIterators.new
puts bi.yield_madness(12, 24){|x, y| puts "x: #{x} and y: #{y}"}
```

Now, the output I'm getting is as follows:

```
dkm@dkm-MasterControl:~/Projects/ruby_playground$ ruby blocks_iterators.rb 
x: 80.2547770700637 and y: 12
my funky pi: 80.2547770700637
my yield:
```

so my question is this - does yield not actually return anything in the traditional sense? I'm not getting any errors here, so I don't think I'm doing anything syntactically incorrect - but my_yield doesn't seem to be returning what it seems it should.
Is there a way to capture the output of yield to a variable?
Is this just something you would never do? I'm just playing around with code here, but I thought this should have been something that might work *shrugs*
At any rate - thanks for anyone who answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your block returns the result of the `puts`, which is `nil`, and in a string winds up being an empty string. use a different block, for example this, and you get a different result:

```
puts bi.yield_madness(12, 24) { |x, y|
  puts "x: #{x} and y: #{y}"
  32
}

x: 80.2547770700637 and y: 12
my_funky_pi: 80.2547770700637
my_yield: 32
=> nil
```

Comment: ooooh. Ok, I gotcha. So, that's why in irb - something like: puts "hello" will print "hello" followed by the line: => nil ... correct? That makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Correct. IRB shows both what will be printed out to standard output (`hello`) and the result of the calculation which [`puts` always returns `nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) :)